# Flexible initial state for scipy solve_ivp used with curve fit

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to fit a differential equation to a small amount of measurements. I am having problems with `solve_ivp` requiring an initial state which I have had to define as a static value. The issue can be seen in the picture below. Everytime the fit is forced to go through the first measurement point when some adjustment would have provided a better fit.

[image: Curve fit to 3 measurement points]

Is there a way to have the initial state `y0` to be flexible inside the `fitfunc` used by `curve_fit`?

I could solve the differential equation and use only `curve_fit` but I would prefer to keep it in my code. In case I have more complex differential equations in the future that cannot be solved in a general way.

```
import scipy.optimize as scopt
import scipy.integrate as scint

def Tdot(t, T, h, X):
    Tdot = -(T - T_inf)*((h*A)/(rho*c*V))
    return Tdot

def do_fit(D, d):
    x_data = D.loc[:, 't'].values
    y_data = D.loc[:, 'T'].values
       
    def fitfunc(t, h):
        y0 = y_data[0]
        
        # Solve differential equation
        sol = scint.solve_ivp(Tdot, [0, np.max(x_data)], [y0], 
                              args = (h, 0),
                              t_eval = x_data, max_step=1e-3)
        
        return sol.y.flatten()
    
    # Fit equation to measurements
    h_fit, kcov = scopt.curve_fit(fitfunc, x_data, y_data, p0=200)
    
    # Limits and values for plotted fit
    tfit = np.linspace(0, D.t.round(1).max())
    fit = scint.solve_ivp(Tdot, [0, np.max(tfit)], [y_data[0]], max_step=1e-3, args=(h_fit, 0))

    return fit, h_fit
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution. Added the initial value to my fitting function and modified the data calculation to match.

`def fitfunc(t, h)` to `def fitfunc(t, h, y0)`,

`h_fit, kcov = scopt.curve_fit(fitfunc, x_data, y_data, p0=200)` to
`popt, _ = scopt.curve_fit(fitfunc, x_data, y_data)`

and

`fit = scint.solve_ivp(Tdot, [0, np.max(tfit)], [y_data[0]], max_step=1e-3, args=(h_fit, 0))` to
`fit = scint.solve_ivp(Tdot, [0, np.max(tfit)], [popt[1]], max_step=1e-3, args=(popt[0], 0))`